# Connect to Wi-Fi programmatically in C ++ / Linux

Tags: c++, linux, wifi

I am creating a program which connects to the WIFI via the network's name and password. I'm able to do it with the system call of the command `nmcli dev wifi connect <mySSID> password <myPassword>`, but I'm not sure that this is the best way of doing this.

For example, how can I handle the incorrect password case? Checking the CERR of the command output isn't really the solution.

I would like to avoid using the system calls. Is there a way of doing this with usual programming, and preferably not very difficult?